# resetting the background image of a UITextField doesn't work

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

Setting a custom background image (for iOS < 5) in the style of a tinted rounded rect text field works fine,
yet I can't change it back to normal or not even to another background image, once it's set.

I'm calling `setBackground:nil` and `setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` on the view in order to reset it.

There is some effect: The edge of the border gets slightly lighter, as if the desired view is drawn behind it, but it's not set back to the normal appearance. Calling `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't help either.

Am I missing another property?